# Why does raising a negative power to both sides of an equation with no variables make sense?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that raising both sides of an equation with a variable makes sense ...

ex: $3x = 6$

$(3x)^{-1} = 6^{-1}$

$1/3x = 1/6$

$3x = 6$

but why does raising a negative power to an equation like 4 = 5 make sense?

$4^{-1} = 5^{-1}$

$1/4 = 1/5$

when now 1/4 is larger. Did the equation flip around? Or does this have something to do with ratios since 4 is 80% of 5 and 1/4 is 80% of 1/5.

Comment: Did you mean to write $4<5$?

Comment: $$4^{-1} = 5^{-1}$$ is a false statement, just like $4=5$ is a false statement.

Comment: Also $3x^{-1} = \frac{3}{x}$.  What you meant to write is $(3x)^{-1} = \frac{1}{3x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you have an expression $A=B$ and you know that $A\neq 0, B\neq 0$, you can conclude that $$A^{-1}=B^{-1}$$ is also true. It doesn't matter if there is a variable in $A$ and $B$.

For example, $10=10$ is true, and $10^{-1}=10^{-1}$ is also true.

---

On the other hand, if $A=B$ is not true, you can't say $A^{-1}=B^{-1}$, and, just like $4=5$ is **not** true, you cannot say $4^{-1}=5^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

The equality $4=5$ is WRONG. Instead, the correct statement is one of inequality: $4 < 5.$

In general, applying operations to the sides of an inequality need not preserve the inequality, unlike in an equality case. Some operations, such as addition of a constant to both sides, does indeed preserve inequality. In mathematical notation, this means that $a<b$ does imply that $a+c<b+c.$ But for the inverse, this is not the case.

You've discovered that $4 < 5$ implies that $4^{-1}>5^{-1}.$ There is nothing wrong with this statement, it simply is a consequence of the fact that inversion does not preserve inequality. In fact, this can be generalized to the statement that $a<b$ implies $\frac 1a > \frac 1b$ for positive $a,b.$ (Can you prove this)?

Answer (score 0):

$$a=b\iff a^{-1}=b^{-1}$$ holds for any $a,b\ne0$.

Hence

$$4=5\iff 4^{-1}=5^{-1}$$

is a perfectly valid logical inference.